# How to reason about equality between different datatypes?

Tags: coq

I am working on a verification project where the specification uses the following inductive datatype to represent bitvectors ([MIT's bbv](https://github.com/mit-plv/bbv))

```
Inductive word : nat -> Set :=
| WO : word O
| WS : bool -> forall n, word n -> word (S n).
```

On the implementation side, however, the EDSL I am using uses [Coq's stdlib Vector](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Vectors.VectorDef.html) to represent bitvectors (with type parameter `A` set to `bool`)

```
Inductive t A : nat -> Type :=
  |nil : t A 0
  |cons : forall (h:A) (n:nat), t A n -> t A (S n).
```

In order to compare the behavior of functions on the implementation side with the spec correspondents, I need to be able to reason about equality between these different datatypes. I have therefore written the following recursive `Prop`, which will generate a rewritable `bool` equality for each bit in the bitvectors.

```
Fixpoint eq_bbvword_bvector {sz} : word sz -> Bvector sz -> Prop :=
        match sz with
        | 0 => fun _ _ => True
        | S n => fun w bv => (whd w) = (Vector.hd bv) /\
        eq_bbvword_bvector (@wtl n w) (Vector.tl bv)
        end.
```

This works fine, but I wanted to able to work with rewritable equalities between `word` and `Bvector` (alias for `Vector bool`) instead of always referring to this predicate to compare.

Any tips on how to do this ?

Comment: You can write a function that converts `Bvector sz` to `word sz` and use equality on the conversion result with `word sz` values.

Comment: Can you give an example of the kind of goals you are aiming at rewriting? Also, your code as is is not self-contained, which makes it harder to help you, because we cannot run it on our side.